# Show that there is a continuous $g$ with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f$ is a measurable complex function (that means that it doesn't take the values $\pm \infty$) with compact support, then for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a continuous $g$ with compact support so that $m(\{f\neq g\})<\epsilon$.

Could you give me some hints how I could show that??

**EDIT:**

Do we have to prove it as followed??

If $f$ is measurable and finite in $\mathbb{R}^d$ then for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a closed $E$ with $m(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus E)<\epsilon$ so that $f|_E$ is continuous.

It is enough to show this in the case in which $f$ is defined in an open bounded cube $Q$ and it is bounded.

Then it is integrable, so there is a sequence of continuous functions $g_n$ so that $||g_n-f||_1 \rightarrow 0$, so there is a subsequence $g_{k_n}$ with $g_{k_n} \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere, so from Egorov theorem, there is $A$ with $m(Q\setminus A)<\epsilon /2$ so that $g_{k_n} \rightarrow f$ uniformly in $A$.

The desired $E$ is a closed subset of $A$ with $m(A\setminus E)<\epsilon /2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [Lusin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem). The proof can be established by invoking [Egoroff's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem) which says that almost sure convergence can be made uniform almost everywhere.

Idea: approximate your $f$ by step functions. Each step function is bounded and can be approximated by a continuous function. Uniform limits of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Ok!! I edited my initial post... Could you tell me if we have to prove that there is the desired $g$ in that way??